# Meaning of 'snuff' as in 'snuff film'

Tags: meaning

*Snuff film* means

> a pornographic film in which one of the actors is murdered during or
>   after a sadistic sexual act.

On the other hand, *snuff* means

> act of inhaling, breathing in; sound made when breathing in; powdered
>   tobacco that is inhaled through the nose; burnt end of a candle wick.

Why is it *snuff* film? What is the meaning of *snuff* as in *snuff film*?

Comment: Actually, a *snuff film* is a for-profit movie consisting of actual murder footage.

Comment: I learnt this term by dint of [Vacancy (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0452702/).

Comment: They fear that they will become part of a movie of their deaths, made by a killer, not that they will end up in a killer porno.

Comment: Correct, but IMDB says _They realize that unless they escape, they'll be the next victims of a snuff film._

Comment: Right. When does it say anything about porn? That just means that if they do not escape, the killer will kill them.

Comment: I didn't know about the term 'snuff film' so I checked a few dictionaries which say it's about pornography (IMDB only says _snuff film_). Do you say _snuff film_ does not necessarily have to mean _porn_?

Comment: Actually, I'm fairly certain that the *main* definition does not involve porn at all. Shall we move this to chat?

Comment: Of course, but I suggest we continue our chat another time as I need to leave now. See you then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2897/discussion-between-mahnax-and-mehper-c-palavuzlar)

Comment: Close "general reference". Wikipedia has a clear and documented etymology in their entry on "snuff film".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=snuff) and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snuff_out), the term *snuff* (out) can be used to mean "to kill". This is probably why they are called snuff films; the character is *snuffed* (killed). This originates from *snuffing out* a candle, that is, extinguishing the flame.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it refers to the [snuffing out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snuff+out) of life:

> snuff someone out
>    Sl. to kill someone.
>
> *Max really wanted to snuff the
>   eyewiteness out, once and for all. Lefty wanted to snuff out his
>   partner.*